# Getting name of button on postback

Tags: button, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, postback, name-attribute

I have built a 'buy products' page dynamically by building it up for each product. Each product has an 'Add to Basket' button, which are differentiated for each product by having the `pID` as the buttons `name` attribute. I now want to get the value of the `name` attribute within my controller on postback. Not sure how to do this:

View:

```
@foreach (Ecommerce.Models.HomeModels.Product product in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.Label(product.Name);
        <br />
        @Html.Label(product.Description);
        <br />
        @Html.Label(product.UnitPrice.ToString());
        <p></p>


        <input name="@product.ID" type="submit" value="Add to Basket" /> 
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult BuyProducts(string button)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have multiple submit buttons inside a form then there is no need to know on the server side what was the name of the clicked submit button. There are other ways to send back your Id to the server:

Why don't you just generate a hidden field inside your form to hold and post the data?

```
@foreach (Ecommerce.Models.HomeModels.Product product in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="@product.ID" />
        <input  type="submit" value="Add to Basket" /> 
    }
}
```

Then you can get the value of the hidden field in your controller:

```
public ActionResult BuyProducts(string productId)
{
    //..
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way of providing this feature? Rather than messing about with product ID's in general?

Comment: No, you need the id becuase somehow you need to tell the server which product is selected. So you need to store somewhere in the Html the product ID and then you need to send it to the server.